# (Android) Error while retrieving music album art from a new thread in Fragment subclass

Tags: android

In Fragment subclass, I created a new Thread and tried to retrieve album bitmap, but application stops working. I used the fragment for ViewPager in MainActivity class using FragmentPagerAdapter.
Here is code for Thread class -

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] columns = {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
            };
            String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1";
            Cursor albumCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, columns, where, null,null);

            if (albumCursor != null && albumCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int albumColumn = albumCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);

                do {
                    long thisAlbum = albumCursor.getLong(albumColumn);
                    Bitmap album = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getCoverArtPath(thisAlbum, getActivity()));
                    if (album == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    albumList.add(album);
                } while (albumCursor.moveToNext());
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        albumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Here is the getCoverArtPath() method i used -

```
  private static String getCoverArtPath(long albumId, Context context) {

    Cursor albumCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(albumId)},
            null
    );
    boolean queryResult = albumCursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = null;
    if (queryResult) {
        result = albumCursor.getString(0);
    }
    albumCursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Please help me out. I am new to Android programming.

Comment: `but application stops working`, how about you post the error that states exactly the reason why it stopped working? Voting to close for lack of details. Check [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have close your cursor before returning result
 --->   albumCursor.close(); 
 Before --->   return result;